# How do I change a list view item dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, listviewitem

I basically want something similar to the Twitter or Pocket app where you long click on an item in the list View and it gives you a set of options to perform on that item by changing the layout of that item, to reveal a set of buttons.

```
ListView lv= getListView();
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v,
            int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        mDbHelper.deleteNotes(id);
        fillData();
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Long Clicked at" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }       
});
```

My long click code is here. Right know I just directly delete the item that is long clicked, but I want the user to see 3-4 buttons when an item is long clicked in place of the said item.

Anyone knows how to do it?

EDIT
Here is the twitter image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is when the user long presses, simply within your adapter, hide or show a, for example, LinearLayout containing all the buttons and so on within it.

Make sure this element you are showing fits itself below or above all other usual elements.

Do you get what I'm trying to say? Holla if you need more info.

### Update 1

Okay so in reply to your comment,  no you won't need to create a separate xml file etc.  See this for example,

Your custom row xml with two layouts:

RelativeLayout mainView

RelativeLayout extraView

In your row xml have an extra layout (my preference is relative, it's upto you anyway), and set this layout to be below the main stuff (make sure they both fit on the row). So in this scenario, mainView is the layout with the stuff you always want shown and extraView is the stuff you want only when long pressed. 
Make sure the default visibility setting for extraView is set as GONE

Then, simply when long pressed, that specific rows extraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

And obviously vice versa when no longer long pressed.

Hit me up if you're confused, and apologies for the non formatted reply as I'm currently commuting and replying via my mobile, will format the answer when at a pc.

Comment: Ok, I kind of understand what you're saying but then how will I get the layout to display at the exact position? Also, I will have to create a separate xml file right for those buttons?

Comment: Sweet! I got a rough implementation of that working! But the problem is that the first item in my listView always disappears rather than the item I am long clicking.

Comment: When you say item, what do you mean? Explain your situation a bit more and we can solve it

Comment: I meant an individual item in the ListView. I worked around this method by having a hover bar appear at the side of the screen. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Oh I see, well it would have just been the case to simply affect that specific views layout. Which i could have provided code